# Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient

Tags: java, netsuite, axis

i'm facing problem with following exception.anyone help me how to get rid of it.i have added axis.jar in classpath still facing this issue.

j

```
ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient 
org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104) 
org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113) 
com.netsuite.webservices.platform_2013_2.NetSuiteServiceLocator.<init>(NetSuiteServiceLocator.java:12) 
com.zyom.netsuite.NetsuiteIntegrationManager.<init>(NetsuiteIntegrationManager.java:169) 
com.zyom.netsuite.NetsuiteIntegrationManager.getNetSuiteIntegrationManager(NetsuiteIntegrationManager.java:68) 
com.zyom.netsuite.controller.NetsuiteIntegrationManagerContoller.execute(NetsuiteIntegrationManagerContoller.java:33) 
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419) 
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224) 
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194) 
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) 
com.zyom.security.LoginMonitorFilter.doFilter(LoginMonitorFilter.java:67)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing some dependant library. In Eclipse you can look inside the jar file from project explorer and verify that there is a package 'org.apache.axis.client' and it contains class AxisClient.

(If you're not in Eclipse then otherwise you can just unpack your jar and see that the class is there - many possibilities for that, you can even rename the jar into zip and unpack it).

If the class file is in place, you're still missing it from classpath.

Comment: i'm using eclipse.it's there in the jar file( AxisClient).checked in classpath also. but dnt knw where i'm wrong

Comment: I guess you are running your application in server (for example, Tomcat) but the libraries added to Eclipse project classpath are not copied to Tomcat 'libs' catalog and not shipped with your war file (you can verify this from exploded catalog in webapps under your application folder -> then 'WEB-INF'/lib. As a quick fix you can add the jar files into Tomcat lib catalog and they will be available to all web applications deployed to your server by default.

Comment: i'm using jboss...how can i check in it?

Comment: I haven't worked with JBoss, but from documentation https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/dirs.html (folder 'lib' in table 3.2) I guess you can put your non-changing jars into catalog similar to 'jboss-4.0.4/server/default/lib'

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add commons-logging and commons discovery dependency jar in the library folder